# how to run this process in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocess

I want to write a multithread code that creates one inference session and run multiple images at the same time.  I found this code created a process, is there any parameters in Process class that could achieve that or should I include multithreading class into this?
Basically what should I do to achieve that based on the code below?

```
import onnxruntime as ort
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp


def init_session(model_path):
    EP_list = ['CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider']
    sess = ort.InferenceSession(model_path, providers=EP_list)
    return sess


class PickableInferenceSession:  # This is a wrapper to make the current InferenceSession class pickable.
    def __init__(self, model_path):
        self.model_path = model_path
        self.sess = init_session(self.model_path)

    def run(self, *args):
        return self.sess.run(*args)

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {'model_path': self.model_path}

    def __setstate__(self, values):
        self.model_path = values['model_path']
        self.sess = init_session(self.model_path)


class IOProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IOProcess, self).__init__()
        self.sess = PickableInferenceSession('model.onnx')

    def run(self):
        print("calling run")
        print(
            self.sess.run({}, {
                'a': np.zeros((3, 4), dtype=np.float32),
                'b': np.zeros((4, 3), dtype=np.float32)
            }))
        #print(self.sess)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method(
        'spawn')  # This is important and MUST be inside the name==main block.
    io_process = IOProcess()
    io_process.start()
    io_process.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain what you are asking, but you may want to try `import multiprocess.dummy as mp` then `mp.Process` is actually uses threading.  If you are asking if there's a keyword to perform multithreading from a process-based `Process` class, the answer is to instead  use the threaded `Process`.  You'll also note that I'm suggesting `multiprocess` instead of `multiprocessing` not only because I'm the author, but because `multiprocess` uses `dill` for pickling to generally simplify the pickling of objects to send to another process/thread.  Also, it seems that from your code, you might want to just try a `Pool` to run in parallel:

```
>>> import multiprocess as mp # or multiprocess.dummy
>>> p = mp.Pool()
>>> p.map(lambda x:x, range(4))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> p.close(); p.join()
```

Comment: I have multiple images loaded by the data loader, and I was hoping that this inference session can process it. SInce I only have a cpu machine, so I was hoping to create multiple threads to process images at the same time. From the example above, I guess I need to do something similiar to  p.map(infer(image), image_list) ?

Comment: yes.  `p.map(infer, image_list)`  The first argument is a function and the second is the list of items to process in parallel.

Comment: ❯ python3 multiprocess.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocess.py", line 1, in <module>
    import multiprocess as mp  # or multiprocess.dummy
  File "/home/users/yue.zhao/task/x3_perf/tmp/multiprocess.py", line 2, in <module>
    p = mp.Pool()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'multiprocess' has no attribute 'Pool' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: seems like it does not have Pool as attribute? I am using version 0.70.15

Comment: You are importing `multiprocess` in a module called `multiprocess`, so it's doing a circular import.  Change the name of your script.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you for the tip!